# It sounds like water dripping when heat runs

Tags: hvac

We have a humidifier and I have shut that off but still hear the sound when the heat runs...anybody know any other possible solutions

---

It's is a carrier weather maker 8000vs energy efficient gas furnace... The noise sounds like it is coming from the vents upstairs the furnace is in the basement

Comment: What do you have for a furnace?

Comment: We have Gas furnace...only does it when heat runs

Comment: ...I could use a make and model number..

Comment: Is the sound coming from the furnace, or somewhere else?

Comment: My gas furnace (Rheem) produces condensation which is emptied into a pump like this http://amzn.com/B000SM342Q After a certain amount is collect the pump kicks on and evacuates the water to my sump pit.  Possibly this is what happening... or worse, the pump is missing?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button underneath your post if you want to add additional information.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you're hearing pinging from expansion and contraction of your ductwork. That often sounds like drops hitting the sheet metal. If you have access to the ducts, look for places where it's rubbing on the framing lumber between fasteners. Loosen the contact points or lubricate them.